# Pip3 is actually running python2?

Tags: python, python3, pip

Could someone please kindly explain to me, why installing `python3-pip` package with `apt` installs `pip3` for... python 2?

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ which pip3 | xargs head -n 1
#!/usr/bin/python
$ ls /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 maj 18  2016 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

I don't know if this should be troubling me this much, but to be in line with XY problem solving: I'm asking because due to this particular setup, many pip3 installs fail - for example, after `sudo -H pip3 install docker-compose`:

```
$ docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..bundle import get_image_digests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/bundle.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .service import format_environment
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from docker.utils import LogConfig
ImportError: cannot import name LogConfig
```

I'm running **Ubuntu GNOME 16.04**

Comment: I don't know where you got `pip3` from, but `python3-pip` contains this as `/usr/bin/pip3`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23667201/ Download from http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/python3-pip/download and see for yourself. Further, why do you have anything Python-related in `/usr/local` at all? It looks like you install Python from source and messed up.

Comment: @muru The package landed inside `/usr/local` after clean reinstall of both the pip and package itself. I have no idea why that happened.  `python3-pip` package came from `pl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-amd64_Packages` (as in `pool/universe/p/python-pip/python3-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb`).

Comment: sorry, but packages from official repos never install anything in `/usr/local`.

Comment: @muru The `/usr/local/` one is not the one from official repo.  `python3-pip` is, `pip3` actually installed it there. For some reason. I reinstalled that with `python3 -m pip install` and it worked as expected. At this point I am afraid to even ask why.

Comment: I fixed `docker-compose` Python issue [with `sudo -H pip install --upgrade docker-py`](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1567#issuecomment-301291916).

Answer (score 4):

Did u try - `sudo -H python3 -m pip install ..`?

Doing `python3 -m pip` will explicitly invoke python3's pip.

Sorry for posting this as answer. I don't have enough reputation to put a comment.

Comment: I know about the command, but the `pip3` thing got me by surprise. By now I'm not sure about the state of any python dependency I installed with pip3, and that makes me kinda nervous. I really wanted to just know why anyone would want that...